# Odoo container : Database connection failure: could not connect to server: Connection refused (linking odoo with localhost postgres)

Tags: linux, docker, odoo

I'm trying to run the odoo docker container and linking it with my local (not container) postgresql.
I tried this command (as suggest [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo/)).

```
docker container run -p 8089:8069 -e HOST=127.0.0.1 -e USER=tux -e PASSWORD=tux --name odoo -t odoo
```

Ran it and got these errors :

```
Database connection failure: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried to open up the port 5432 with ufw but got the same erros. I also tried to change 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 but nothing.
Could you help me?

ps : the USER and PASSWORD are corrects, I use them when I run odoo instance in my local.

Comment: you might need to add the host network with a flag `--network=host`

Comment: @ErikK, but got this "WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode", is this security issues?

Comment: hey if you could accept my answer that would be great. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might need to add the host network with a flag `--network=host`

`WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode`
that just means you cannot change the port bindings. thats as secure as your machine is.